Solution of $A\mathbf{x}=0$ when $A$ is in Row Echelon Form
Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix in Row Echelon Form, and consider the homogeneous system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. If $A$ has $k$ non-zero rows, then  $A$ has rank $k$, and by the rank and nullity theorem, the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $n-k$. There will be $n-k$ free variables when we solve the system by back substitution (starting at the bottom), and then we get a basis for the Null Space of $A$ by simply "separating" the free variables. This is illustrated in an example in the book "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Howard Anton (10th ed. Example 4 on page 210), where he finds that for the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 &-2 & 0 & 2 & 0\\2&6&-5&-2&4& -3\\ 0&0&5&10&0&15\\2&6&0&8&4&18
\end{pmatrix}$, after reducing it to Row Echelon Form,  the solution is found to be $(-3t_1-4t_2-2t_3,t_1,-2t_2,t_2, t_3,0)$, that can be written as $t_1(-3,1,0,0,0,0)+t_2(-4,0,-2,1,0,0)+t_3(-2,0,0,0,1,0)$ and the three vectors $(-3,1,0,0,0,0),(-4,0,-2,1,0,0),(-2,0,0,0,1,0)$ are a basis for the Null Space of $A$.
Here is my question: how can we prove in general that the process of separating the free variable will always produce linearly independent vectors? In his book, Anton writes: "the method [...] always produces a basis for the solution space of the system. We omit the formal proof." and I have not been able to find a proof in full generality in other books.

Your example does not fit the statement of the problem: your matrix $A$ is not in row echelon form.

The vectors obtained by separating the free variables clearly span the null space of $A$. The number of these vectors is $n-k$ which is also $\dim \ker A$ by the rank-nullity theorem. Therefore these vectors form a basis of $\ker A$.
Another proof is given in the Wikipedia page about the rank-nullity theorem.

Let me name your three vectors $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, $\vec v_3$. Also let me introduce coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ for vectors in the row space $\mathbb R^6$.
Here's the pattern to notice: the free variables are $x_2=t_1$, $x_4=t_2$ and $x_5=t_3$. Furthermore,

The only vector with nonzero $x_2$ is $\vec v_1$
The only vector with nonzero $x_4$ is $\vec v_2$
The only vector with nonzero $x_5$ is $\vec v_3$

So for any linear dependence equation of the form $c_1 \vec v_1 + c_2 \vec v_2 + c_3 \vec v_3=0$,

from the $x_2$ coordinate we get $c_1=0$,
from the $x_4$ coordinate we get $c_2=0$,
from the $x_5$ coordinate we get $c_5=0$.

Now generalize this pattern: one gets a one-to-one correspondence between free variables of the solution and vectors of the basis, such that each free variable has a nonzero value only in its corresponding vector. Using this pattern, one proves that the coefficients of any linear dependence equation are zero.
